# Запрос на вывод количества покупок и имени клиента

Tags: mysql

Как мне составить запрос на вывод количества покупок и имени клиента, с группировкой по именам клиента, если моя таблица выглядит примерно так:

```
клиенты( id_клиента, имя клиента);
продажа(id_продажи, id_клиента);
журнал продаж (id_продажи, количество);
```

Comment: Что это Вы пытаетесь нарисовать? Может лучше скриншот тогда?

Comment: я могу вывести отдельно имена и количество, но вместе не могу

Answer (score 4):

```
select количество, имя клиента from клиенты
inner join продажа on (клиенты.id_клиента = продажа.id_клиента)
inner join журнал продаж on (журнал продаж.id_продажи = продажа.id_продажи)
```

думаю как то так

Comment: спасибо. все работает

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT clients.name, SUM(sales_journal.count)
FROM clients, sales, sales_journal
WHERE clients.id = sales.client_id AND sales.id = sales_journal.sale_id
GROUP BY clients.id;
```

Comment: а зачем использовать вложенные запросы вместо произведения таблиц?